# How to display array items across multiple rows in an Angular app

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

In my Angular app, I have an array of companies in my *.ts file*, which are being displayed in my HTML using **ngFor** in the following code:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let company of companies">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">         
             {{ company.companyName }}
          </h5>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above card deck displays the entire list of companies in one row.

For example, if there are 3 companies then they are displayed in one row across the screen. If there are 10 companies, they're displayed in one row.

Can someone please let me know what changes I'd need to make either to my TS or HTML, so that I can set the number of companies in each row? I.e. Only display max 3 companies on one row, then move onto the next row.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy method would be just add some `style` to your card `div` like:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let company of companies" style="width:33%; display: inline-block; text-align: center">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">         
             {{ company.companyName }}
          </h5>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You can view the output of above code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbwel.png)

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution, you can create multidimensional array from `companies` and use two `*ngFor` (iterate over rows, and then iterate over `companies`).

```
// component.ts

companies = [{
    companyName: 'first'
  },
  {
    companyName: 'second'
  },
  {
    companyName: 'third'
  }
  ...
] // for example, ten elements in companies

companiesInRow: number = 3; // number of companies in row
rows;

ngOnInit() {
  // create multidimensional array
  this.rows = this.companies.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
    if (index % this.companiesInRow == 0 && index !== 0) acc.push([])
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(value)
    return acc;
  }, [[]]);
}


// component.html
<div class="card-deck" *ngFor="let comps of rows">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let company of comps">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">         
         {{ company.companyName }}
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/start-project-fjvjvn)